# Celery Integration Testing

Tags: celery, integration-testing, celery-task

Im trying to write integration tests for a celery server I wrote.
The celery app has 1 task which I want to test.
I've tried to execute my celery_server.py file using subprocess library.
Also I've tried importing the celery_app directly from the file and starting it and then sending the tasks.
but it does not work.

I've tried using the subprocess:

```
self._celery_server_process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", path_to_celery_server])
```

then in the test:

```
        res_handle = task.delay(data)
        res = res_handle.get()
```

but it always hangs on the get() function, probably because the server does not actually start.